# Precise math.log(x, 2) in Python

Tags: python, binary, logarithm

In python, I need to get the rounded down logarithm of positive integers for base 2, including big numbers.

However, since floating point math is used, I might get bad results, for example:

```
>>> import math
>>> int(math.log(281474976710655, 2))
48
```

However:

```
>>> 2 ** 48
281474976710656
```

So the correct result, rounded down, should be 47.

How can I get the correct value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, integers have a `.bit_length` method, so you should use that to get your rounded down base 2 logarithm.

Here's a short demo:

```
m = 2 ** 1000
for n in (281474976710655, m-1, m, m+1):
    a = n.bit_length() - 1
    b = 2 ** a
    print(a, b <= n < 2 * b)
```

**output**

```
47 True
999 True
1000 True
1000 True
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 `int`s even have an efficient `.bit_length()` method!

```
>>> (281474976710655).bit_length()
48
>>> (281474976710656).bit_length()
49
```

In python 2, instead of using floating point math, count the number of bits:

```
def log2(n):
    assert n >= 1
    return len(bin(n)) - 3  # bin() returns a string starting with '0b'
```

(**Edited** following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121567/precise-math-logx-2-in-python/41121568#comment69447333_41121568))

Comment: That's fine for Python 2, but in Python 3 `.bit_length` is much more efficient than converting the number to a binary string. BTW, in Python 2.6+ `format(n, 'b')` is more convenient for this than `bin`, since you don't get that pesky `'0b'`.